# Проверка правильной загрузки файла

Tags: laravel, html, php

Здравствуйте!

Проект на Laravel.
Есть форма, где одним из input-ов есть поле с типом file. Должны загружаться файлы типа
pdf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx. Соответственно, есть валидация на типы файлов:

```
$rules = array(
    'cv' => 'required|mimes:pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx'
);
```

А можно ли как-то проверять,  что загрузка не была прервана пользователем и  файл загружен полностью и готов к отправке?

Comment: По размеру файла? Браузер, насколько я помню, отправляет информацию о размере. 
Также, хотя боюсь сглупить, может быть md5?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант средставми JS(Есть много библиотек) есть хорошая библиотека [Dropzone](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/howto-ajax-multiple-file-upload-in-laravel/)